# How to make an equidepth histogram using Hadoop

Tags: java, algorithm, hadoop

I need the logic to implement Equidepth histogram using hadoop.

Say we have the following test data:

```
10, 11, 14, 16, 80, 90, 65
```

How do I the equi depth histogram ?

I have to variable `params`, number of items per bucket and items per bucket.

How should I implement it ?

The logic I think is to find the equi width histogram. Calculate the average frequency. And perform the map reduce again on the input data. If so how to read two input files (input data and result from map reduce 1)

Is there any other logic ?